# Can you identify this piece of non-LEGO submarine from a sketch?

Tags: piece-information, part-identification, clone-brands, 3rd-party

This is from a submarine set I bought on aliexpress. It's not LEGO but usually the pieces are the same. I'm missing this piece and cannot identify it.  Can you guys help me?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for the LEGO equivalent of it, it's a Slope, Curved 2 x 2 No Studs, 3 Side Ports Recessed: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44675#T=P